# SQL: Pegar a ultima informação de uma tabela com um campo específico

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando fazer um Select, no qual quero retornar a ultima atualização de uma tabela que tenha um valor em específico em um campo.

Minhas tabelas são essas:

ORDEM

| ID | STATUS | DATA | SITUACAO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2509 | 3 | 18-04-2023 | 5 |
| 2508 | 5 | 18-04-2023 | 4 |
| 2500 | 5 | 18-04-2023 | 4 |

RELACIONAMENTO

| ID | STATUS | ORDEM | DATA | SITUACAO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | 3 | 2509 | 18-04-2023 | 5 |
| 998 | 5 | 2500 | 18-04-2023 | 4 |
| 997 | 5 | 2508 | 18-04-2023 | 4 |
| 996 | 4 | 2500 | 17-04-2023 | 3 |

STATUS

| ID | NOME |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Modificado |
| 4 | Livre |
| 3 | Tratando |
| 1 | Cancelado |

Estou fazendo a Query assim:

```
SELECT UPPER(B.NOME) SITUACAO, 
       COUNT(A.ID) QUANTIDADE, 
       ISNULL(MAX(C.DATA),MAX(A.DATA))  ATUALIZADO, 
       ISNULL(MAX(C.NUMERO), MAX(A.ORDEM)) HD
FROM ORDEM A
INNER JOIN STATUS B ON B.ID = A.STATUS
LEFT JOIN RELACIONAMENTO C ON C.ID = (
    SELECT MAX(C2.ID)
    FROM RELACIONAMENTO C2
    WHERE C2.ORDEM = A.ID
       AND C2.STATUS NOT IN (1,9,10)
)
WHERE B.ID NOT IN (1,9,10)
GROUP BY B.NOME
ORDER BY B.NOME ASC
```

Nesse Select, eu gostaria de, por exemplo, pegar a ultima 'Ordem' que teve no 'Relacionamento', agrupado pela 'Situação'.

Comment: Por que você teria os dados duplicados da **ordem** em **relacionamento**?

Comment: Última ordem significa aquela cuja a data de emissão  seja a mais próxima ou igual a data de hoje?

Comment: Poderia por favor esclarecer qual o problema com a consulta usada na pergunta e em que podemos a melhorar? Se é que podemos.

Comment: A tabela 'Relacionamento' é utilizada para fazer alterações (e manter registrado) nas 'Ordens', por exemplo, quando quero alterar o campo 'Status' na 'Ordem', é criada uma linha na tabela 'Relacionamento', referenciando a Ordem e alterando os campos.

Comment: A 'ultima ordem' que me referencio é a ultima 'Ordem' que aparece na tabela 'Relacionamento' para cada Status (Ultima ordem que tem o Status 5, ultima ordem que tem o Status 3)

Comment: Na consulta, ela me estou utilizando o MAX(C.ID), para saber qual o ultimo Relacionamento, mas, se eu utilizo o MAX(C.ORDEM), no caso do Status 5, ele irá me retornar a Ordem 2508, ao invés do que eu quero, que seria a 2500.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui puxar a informação que eu queria, não sei se é o modo mais performático ou com as melhores 'boas práticas'.

Realizei a seguinte alteração

```
SELECT UPPER(B.NOME) SITUACAO, 
       COUNT(A.HANDLE) QUANTIDADE, 
       ISNULL(MAX(C.DATA),MAX(A.DATA))  ATUALIZADO, 
       ISNULL((
              SELECT ORDEM 
              FROM RELACIONAMENTO X
              WHERE X.ID = MAX(C.ID)
              AND X.STATUS NOT IN (1,9,10)
              ), MAX(A.ID)) HD
FROM ORDEM A
INNER JOIN STATUS B ON B.ID = A.STATUS
LEFT JOIN RELACIONAMENTO C ON C.ID = (
    SELECT MAX(C2.ID)
    FROM RELACIONAMENTO C2
    WHERE C2.ORDEM = A.ID
       AND C2.STATUS NOT IN (1,9,10)
)
WHERE B.ID NOT IN (1,9,10)
GROUP BY B.NOME
ORDER BY B.NOME ASC
```